# Java Multiple markers at this line

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, starting to learn the basics. I just ran into this error which I can't comprehend or find an answer to. The error happens at for(int d ; d < 4; d++).

```
public class ArraysLists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,3,2)); 
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myarray));
        Collections.sort(list);
        list.add(6);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));

        for(int d ; d < list.size(); d++){
            System.out.println(list.get(d));
        }
    }
```

Comment: *this error*: WHICH error? Reading it might help.

Comment: You forgot `=0` after the declaration. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: error's in the title

Comment: No. That's an indication from your IDE that there are errors/warnings at this line. The error from the compiler is elsewhere (depends on your IDE). If you don't know how to read the errors from the compiler, that's the very first thing you should figure out. The actual error message is probably something like "variable d has not been initialized", which explains exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Give an initial value to `d`, like `d=0`

```
for(int d=0; d < list.size(); d++){
    System.out.println(list.get(d));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize d=0.

for(int d=0; d < list.size(); d++)